# @tanstack/vue-query using Paginated / Lagged Queries but isLoading state is always false

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tanstackreact-query

I have a problem using `useQuery` in Vue.js. I follow the documentation for paginated queries in @tanstack/vue-query documentation but `isLoading` state is always false. I need `isLoading` state for show the loading spinner in My Custom DataTables.

Here's the code :

```
const getData = async (page: Ref<number>): Promise<PaginationData<User>> => {
    const response = await ApiService.get("/api/users", {
        page: page.value,
    });
    return response.data;
};
const queryClient = useQueryClient();

const { isLoading, isError, data, error, isFetching, isPreviousData } =
    useQuery({
        queryKey: ["pagination", currentPage],
        queryFn: () => getData(currentPage),
        keepPreviousData: true,
        queryClient,
    });
```

Comment: Please. provide a way to reproduce the problem. Sounds like a bug that needs to be debugged

Comment: @EstusFlask i've tried using this code from documentation https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/vue/guides/paginated-queries but it's still isLoading always false even though i've click next page

Comment: I see. A way to reproduce the problem is necessary from you, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . The code from documentation alone isn't useful because it's obviously expected to work. As said, could be a bug, but bug report would require the reproduction too.